# iPad gets amazon pop ups to win prizes answer 3question?

Tags: ipad

How do I stop this annoying pop up on iPad the latest edition bought this winter . Always amazon answer three stupid question and get say $1000.
Always I delete and not open . Happens when in browser.

Want this to stop

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the latest version of iOS.  Follow these steps to block Safari browser plugins:

1. Open `Settings` app.
2. Scroll down and tap `Safari`.
3. On the right-side of the screen, under the `General` section, turn on `Block Pop-ups`.
   [image]

Also, if you use the Amazon app and not the browser, you will not see any pop-ups.

Comment: The pop ups are blocked  and I usually am accessing a group.